# Program to reverse an inputted chain of characters

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, reverse

I need to make a program that lets the user enter a string character by character and then print it in reverse. <kbd>space</kbd> means end of input (<kbd>space</kbd> should be entered by user.)

```
section .bss
c : resb 1
section .text
global _start
_start :
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
saisie :
    push ecx    
    push edx
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,c
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    mov ecx,[c] ; put the entered value in ecx
    cmp ecx,32  ; compare ecx with space.
    je espace   ;
    pop edx 
    inc edx
    pop ecx
    jmp saisie
espace :
    pop edx
    cmp edx,0 ; if counter is 0 we exit if not we print what's in stack.
    je fin
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    pop ecx
    int 80h 
    dec edx
    jmp espace
fin :
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

When I enter characters and <kbd>space</kbd> at the end, the program just exits without error like it has done its job.

Can anyone explain this behavior and how I can correct it?

Comment: Have you attempted to step through the code using _gdb_ (debugger) . If not accustomed to gdb's text interface you might have _ddd_ available on your Linux platform. _DDD_ is one of the graphical interfaces to _GDB_

Comment: You forgot to comment your code. Also, you haven't run it in a debugger. That said, I don't see any sign of you storing the characters and also the printout code makes no sense to me. Furthermore, you load 32 bits from a 8 bit variable.

Comment: I'll try to see how to run the code through a debugger and see what happens